If we found a way to make highly electrically conductive wires, would it be useful?
I'm thinking we need that very damaging and destructive high voltage power in those wires before we use a converter to lower the voltage in households. I don't seem to be able to prove there isn't gonna be an error with that. Or having holes to look out for of doing things with so much power through a wave making machine like the one in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMyftvliUgg. Or maybe it could be used for lightning rods to carry the highly charged electric monopole Earth fed it into the ocean which is a huge body of very electrically conductive salt water. I just want to know if you can find a source with experience to build on with a very simple general summary of the answer that I will be able to understand. I don't have the right experience to make any sense of the questions that pop up in the review before posting this one.
